# Navigation, Flyouts menus

Tags: asp.net, navigation

Is it possible to customize the SharePoint top navigation with fly-out menus that display sub-sites?

Comment: There are quite a few similar posts in the related column as well.  Though you provided your own answer, you can still mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

[MSDN: How to: Customize the Display of Quick Launch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms466994.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure it out myself and here is the solution

Here is my Taxonomy   | Canada | Ontario | Toronto | North York |
When I move the mouse over to Canada, I want to see all the sub sites in flyouts menu

Before Modification:

[image]

Now I am going make some changes to the master page to have four level flyouts. 
Open your SharePoint site using SharePoint designer 2010 and edit your master page

[image]

By default the Maximum Dynamic Display Level is 1 and I am going to change to 4

Now search for “topNavigationDelegate” and change the values to “True”

ShowStartingNode="True"
SiteMapProvider="SPSiteMapProvider"

[image]

and remove "StartingNodeUrl="sid:1002"

Save your master page and publish. Make sure your sub sites SharePoint Server Publishing features are actives

This is the end result

[image]